# preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new in laravel. I am try to insert all the checked values of checkbox into database table one colume such as stationary=">Table/Chair Arrangemen,Mike/Speaker Testing,..." .
I am greatful and thankful if anyone can solve this problem
When I am trying below code for that I get the error that mentioned above  heading

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lead">List of Stationaries</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_of_stationary[]" value="Table/Chair Arrangement">Table/Chair Arrangement<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_of_stationary[]" value="Projector Testing">Projector Testing<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_of_stationary[]" value="Mike/Speaker Testing">Mike/Speaker Testing<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_of_stationary[]" value="Laptop/Desktop">Laptop/Desktop<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_of_stationary[]" value="Handsout Ready">Handsout Ready
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="stationaries">Stationaries</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="stationary_done_date" value="" placeholder="Stationaries Done Date">
  </div>
  </div>
```

My controller function to store data into database is:-

```
  public function store(StationaryRequest $request)
   {   

    $st = new Stationary();


     $st -> stationary_done_date = $request->stationary_done_date;

    $st->list_of_stationary=$request->list_of_stationary


      $st -> save();


  return redirect()->back()->with('message','Stationary Added');
 }
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 674: